# Резервная копия убунту

Tags: ubuntu

Делаю всё по инструкции «[Восстановление GRUB](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_grub)» на сайте Ubuntu. Дошел до пункта:

> Теперь подключим этот раздел в /mnt следующей командой (следим за пунктуацией, особенно, за пропусками между кодами):
>
> ```
> sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
> ```

Однако эта команда выдаёт ошибку:

```
mount: block device /dev/vda1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

[image: Экранный снимок консоли]

Comment: Я так понимаю, он не может подключить таблицу разделов потому что в режиме read-only, а в режиме read-only потому что с диска грузится

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на этот вопрос можете дать только вы:

> > mount: you must specify the filesystem type

Какая у вас файловая система на /dev/sda1? ext2, ext3, ext4, xfs, zfs? Вас просто указать, что там было, потому что mount не может её автоматически определить.

Можно попорбовать проверить dmesg или через fsck - возможно они покажут, что у вас там живет.

Comment: Я так понимаю, он не может подключить таблицу разделов потому что в режиме read-only, а в режиме read-only потому что с диска грузится